# Replace middle string by passing specific pattern

Tags: php, string

I want to replace a middle string by passing the pattern. I have tried it by using pre_replace function. But it is not working for me.

```
   $str = "Lead for Nebhub - Admark
          Name: Punam Kalbande
          Email: kalbandepunam@gmail.com
          Phone Number: 800-703-3209
          Nebhub Partner : Nebhub - Admark
          Address: PO Box 830395 Miami, FL 33173
          Hub : Automotive
          Products: ERP, CRM, HCM, Help Desk, Marketing";
  $pattern = '/^Hub :(.+)Products:$/i';
  $replacement = "Logistics";
  $result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

but the above code is only returning original string. It is not replacing with  the new one.

Comment: You should use add multi-line option to replace data on two differents lines. However, the expression will not match as the "$" means the end of the content. You should experiment with an interactive regular expression tester like https://regex101.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The s-Modifier is missing in your Pattern. Further you want to match the Pattern somewhere in the middle of the Text. You used ^, which indicates the Start of the Line and $ which indicates the End of the Line. That means, the whole String must match. Use this Regex, and it will work for you.

```
/(Hub :)[^\n]+/is
```

Explanation:

```
(        start Subpattern
Hub      the Word Hub
         followed by a space
:        followed by a Doubledot 
)        end Subpattern -> accessible by $1 or \1
[^\n]+   match one or more Characters except a Linebreak

i        Modifier for caseinsensitive Search
s        Modifier to include Linebreaks
```

What you have to do now is to output the Subpattern in the Replacement too:

```
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "$1$replacement", $str);
```

Comment: Well, I checked it again and updated my Answer. Check it out.

Comment: Hi Bernhard, Thanks for the reply. 
It is now replace by string from Hub : to Products:. I want to replace only the middle string which comes in between Hub: to Product:

Comment: Hey bernhard, It is now replaceing the "Hub : " with the replaced word. I dont want that. I wanted to replace the next string of "Hub :" and before the "Product :".

Comment: Hello, I guess you forgot to include the $1 in the Replacement like in my Example.

Comment: No, I have added that to.

Comment: Which Regex did you use?

Comment: I am using $re = '/(Hub :)[^\n]+\is/';

I tried this too.
/(Hub :)[^\n]+/is

Comment: Hi...Now its done.. Thanx a lot..
Actually the problem was with the space which we are passing before logistic word.
Thx a lot again..

Comment: hey Bernhard, I need some more help in that.
Actually, It is now replacing the all contents after "Hub : " which is wrong. It should only  replace all middle string upto "Product :"

Comment: Try [^\r\n] instead of [^\n]